# Hive join tables on string field match

Tags: hiveql

Hi I am trying to Left outer join on table onto another, the matching colums are type String.

Will Hive join on matching string columns or do they need to be converted to a different datatype?

My join ON Clause looks like 
Select table1.para1, table2.para2
From table a
left outer Join Table b
On (table1.a=table2.b). A and B are strings, will this work?

Comment: It's very simple to check. What is your doubt? that this will not work with string datatype? It should and depends only on data. Will join if there are same values in both tables and will not if there are none of such.

Answer (score 0):

Join on string will work. Just keep in mind that string matching will be **case-sensitive**.

Consider using functions like UPPER or LOWER.

For example,

```
select * from temp join new_temp on LOWER(temp.dept) = LOWER(new_temp.dept);
```